# Probability that a number is a root to a polynomial in a polynomial field

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Consider a polynomial in a field $F$ which is a finite field on a prime $p$. Consider a polynomial
$$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3....a_{n-1}x^{n-1}$$ The polynomial has a special property that all $a_0,a_1...a_{n-1}\in\{0,1,p-1\}$ with at least one of the coefficients being non zero, with $p \geq 4n$.

Find the probability that a number $k \leq n $ chosen uniformly in the range is a solution to this equation.

The answer given is $\frac{n-1}{4n}$, since $k$ is chosen uniformly and it can have at most $n-1$ roots.

I just don't understand anything about the solution.

Comment: Is $F=\mathbb{F}_p$, or is $F=\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$?

Comment: Not a prime power.

Answer (score 0):

If you let $a_0$ run through all the numbers from $0$ to $p-1$, then each $k$ is a root once.  So I would say the chance is $1/p$.
The exception is when $a_1,...,a_{n-1}$ are all zero, in which case $a_0=0$ is not allowed.  So a better answer would be $(p^{n-1}-1)/(p^n-1)$.

Comment: Running through the $a_0$ like this, you do hit $p$ different roots, but there is no reason to expect that these roots are necessarily less than $n$, so this logic does not hold.

Comment: If you fix $k$, then about $1/p$ of the polynomials have $k$ as a root; whether $k$ is in the range or not.  Since there is randomness, I assume the polynomial is picked randomly as well.

Comment: Also, that's just one root.  When you change $a_0$, you are changing all the roots.

Comment: The proportion of $(k,P(x))$ with $P(k)=0$ is $1/p$ because you can group the $P(k)$ into sets of size $p$, exactly one of which has $k$ as a root.

Comment: No the polynomial is fixed, The number $k$ is chosen uniformly form $1$ to $\frac{p}{4}$, what is the probability of $k$ being a root of a fixed polynomial

Comment: That depends on the polynomial.  The probability for $(x-3)^3$ is different from the probability for $(x-1)(x-2)$.

Comment: I too think the same but i think the question means the maximum probability.